# How do I know the length of a perpendicular drawn from a vertex of a triangle to the opposite arm?

Tags: geometry, triangles

Here's the question I am trying to solve-

> The [points] $A$, $B$, $C$ have respective co-ordinates $(3, 4)$, $(-4, 3)$ and $(8, -6)$. Find the area of $\Delta ABC$ and the length of the perpendicular from $A$ on $BC$.

Now, calculating the area is the easy part. I can do that. But how do I get the length of the perpendicular drawn from A on BC?

Now, if it were a median, I could have found out the co-ordinates of the point where the line touches the side. But this is not a median, rather a perpendicular. How can I know where it touches the side?

Is there some special property that can help me solve this problem? What am I missing?

It's also obvious that the perpendicular creates two Right triangles. That somehow helpful?

Comment: The triangle isn't close to being isosceles.  Have you typed the coordinates correctly?

Comment: It's easy to calculate the length of $BC$, so you can get the altitude from the formula for the area of a triangle, as you already know the area.

Comment: Use the [shoelace formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shoelace_formula) to compute the area of the triangle, then divide by $\tfrac12BC$.

Comment: Use analytic geometry to determine the point on the height on opposite side. Then calculate segment length  of the height.

Comment: @saulspatz that's really helpful. Feeling stupid now, btw. Thanks a lot. I missed it. I edited the question and removed the sentence about it being isosceles.

Comment: @Servaes That's really helpful. Thanks.

Comment: A (longer) way to find the length of the altitude required (but without first having to calculate the area of the triangle) is to first find the equation of the line $BC,$ and from there we can find the equation of the line defined by the altitude wanted since this is perpendicular to the line $BC.$ Once one has these equations, one finds their point of intersection, say $P.$ Then $|AP|$ is the required quantity.